# Save parsed content in plain text with BeautifulSoup without <p></p>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can i save the parsed content into a plain text in a .txt file?

If i parse the text from a div i get the results with `<p>content here</p>` in my saved save.txt file. i want to save it as a plain text without `<p></p>` in my save.txt file. How can i do that?

Right now my python script is parsing the content of this div :

```
<div itemprop="text"><p>content here</p></div>
```

This is my **bs4** script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('var/www/html/audi/index.html', 'r') as f:
    feed = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(feed, 'html.parser')
for elem in soup.find("div", {"itemprop":"text"}):
 print(elem.text)

with open("/var/www/html/audi/save.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(elem))
```

Everything works fine and the script saves the content into a save.txt file with the `<p></p>` ; like: `<p>content here</p>` BUT i want to save it without the `<p></p>` like: `content here`

I tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('var/www/html/audi/index.html', 'r') as f:
    feed = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(feed, 'html.parser')
for elem in soup.find("div", {"itemprop":"text"}):

 elem = data.get_text()
 print(elem.text)

with open("/var/www/html/audi/save.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(elem))
```

But i can't get it working.

Can someone help me with this please?

P.S: It needs to parse the div content **WITHOUT** the `<p>` (sometimes the p data content is **different** then: content here)
Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer right there in your post.

Writing `str(elem)` won't work properly, as you mentioned.
Writing `elem.text` suffices.

---

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> feed = '<div>stuff<p>content here</p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(feed, 'html.parser')
>>>
>>> soup.find('p')
<p>content here</p>
>>>
>>> soup.find('p').text
'content here'
```

Comment: thanks for your effort sir. but please read the other answer comments. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To cut out from this `<p>content here</p>` to `content here` this, you could
do just a simple slicing like below.

```
elm = '<p>content here</p>'
elm = elm[3:-4]
```

then you will get `elm = 'content here'`
hoping this will solve your problem

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. No that is not gonna help because the content here is just a example. Its need to parse random texts from the file so sometimes the data is different. you get me?

Comment: content here is just a example. the data of the div is everything different then content here